# How can I solve this error " too many indices for array in my data ?"

Tags: python

This type of data contains, integers either positive and negative and whole numbers this file has an array of 368 rows and 143 columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

databogota2 = pd.read_csv('datosairebogota.csv')

#List of the atributes 
list(databogota2.columns.values)

df = databogota2.drop(databogota2.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1)
df1 = df.drop(df.index[367])
df2 = df1.iloc[:,:].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values= np.nan, strategy='mean' , axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(df2[:,0:144])
df2[:,0,144] = imputer.transform(df2[:,0,144])

#I will expect to get as output that the "nan" values become filling for     mean of the columns each.
```

This is the error it generates.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-60-7cca9cc68b6f>", line 5, in <module>
df2[:,0,144] = imputer.transform(df2[:,0,144])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I was trying to solve the problem by looking some wrong format into the file however it has not solved the problem.

Comment: Please post the full error, mainly, tell us where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want column 0 to 144. If I am getting your problem than you can do this to get out your problem.

`df.iloc[:,0:144]` means you are getting all the rows of column 0 to 144.

Change your last line to

```
df2.iloc[:,0:144] = imputer.transform(df2.iloc[:,0:144])

df2.iloc[starting_index_of_row:ending_index_of_row , starting_index_of_column:ending_index_of_column]
```

I hope my answer will solve your problem thank you.